# Auto goto next scene without button click as3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5

Is it possible to go to next scene in flash Cs5 using acs3 after a certain activity is done in the one scene? If possible, how can this be accomplished?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

add '`stop`' to prevent errors then code for next scene.

```
stop();
gotoAndStop(1, "NameofYourScene");
```

If you're in a MovieClip, change `gotoAndStop` to `MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop` and add `this.parent.removeChild(this);`

Answer (score 0):

Actionscript 3.0

MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop(1, "NameofYourScene");

this worked for me without error if you're in a movie clip jumping from scene to scene